# Insert text into messenger.com message box using Javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook, keypress, messenger

My extension allows users to enter predefined text into textboxes and content editable divs.

Messenger.com message box is a contenteditable div. Normally I would insert text into such a node using

```
txt = 'hello'
g = document.createTextNode(txt)
f = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0)
f.insertNode(g)
f.collapse()
f.setStart(g, txt.length)
f.setEnd(g, txt.length)
window.getSelection().removeAllRanges()
window.getSelection().addRange(f)
g.parentNode.normalize()
```

However, it is not possible to insert text using this method in Messenger. Is it possible to simulate a user typing using keypress events and actually have text inserted into the textbox ?

Comment: Pretty sure any such attempts would be against Messenger’s terms & conditions.

Comment: I also found that this is not possible :/